# Botón angularjs, que guarde o actualice los registros

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un botón angularjs el cual ya me guarda los registros del formulario sobre un ID.

Ahora lo que tengo que hacer es que el mismo botón en la misma pagina me actualice la respuesta del formulario en caso de ya existir el mismo ID de registro(Solucionado).

Mi problema esta en como hacer que el mismo botón y función guarde y actualice. Aquí mi código del botón con la directiva `ng click="btnGuardar()`:

```
<button type="button" id="btnGuardarID" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="btnGuardar()">Continuar<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"> </span>
</button>
```

Aquí el código de mi función:

```
$scope.btnGuardar = function(test){
    console.log('entro a btnAplicarBDL::');
   
    console.log('conoce TP ',$scope.RespConoceTp);
    console.log('Provedor Internet:: ',$scope.RespProvedorInternet);

    var objRespuestas = {};
    objRespuestas = {
        ApexConoceTp: $scope.RespConoceTp,
    };
    
    $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

Comment: te referís a que muestre un mensaje de error tipo "El registro ya existe" o que?

Comment: Me refiero que el mismo boton me actualize el registro sobre la misma funcion del boton, pero desconozco como hacerlo

Comment: Fácil, cuando sea una creación, enviale un id 0, undefined o lo que sea, y en tu back manejas el id de forma autoincremental (si estas usando alguna BD SQL); si quieres actualizar, le envias el id del elemento a actualizar.

Comment: le llamas registro a esta variable `$scope.RespConoceTp`? y necesitas guardar eso en una base de datos o donde? explicate un poco mas claro por favor. Por lo que puedo ver lo único que hace tu función es meter esa variable global en la propiedad de un objeto local y nada más.